# Error in installing libact on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-17.10

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on a virtual machine from a windows 8 PC.
I'm using python3.6 on Ubuntu. After following the installation process from [ntucllab repo](https://github.com/ntucllab/libact) I got stuck in the commande

> sudo pip install libact

that showed the error

> /usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -llapacke -llapack -lblas
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/libact/query_strategies/src/variance_reduction/variance_reduction.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/libact/query_strategies/_variance_reduction.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -llapacke -llapack -lblas" failed with exit status 1
>
> ---
>
> Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u
>   -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-81gabwt_/libact/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-record-0aofup63/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-81gabwt_/libact/

I've been trying to find a solution for days and I couldn't find anything

Comment: The repo says you first must install `libact` dependencies listed in the `requirements.txt`: https://github.com/ntucllab/libact/blob/master/requirements.txt. (`setuptools`, `numpy`, `scipy`, `scikit-learn`, `matplotlib`, `Cython`,`joblib`). But even if you do that, the `README` lists up to Python3.5, (Python `2.7`, `3.3`, `3.4`, `3.5`) so maybe your python3.6 is not *yet* supported? Possibly try with `Python <= version 3.5`?